# How to properly use StreamProvider that rely on another StreamProvider?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-provider

I have pretty similar question with this:

[How to setup StreamProvider which take a param value from another StreamProvider?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57688304/how-to-setup-streamprovider-which-take-a-param-value-from-another-streamprovider)

But the problem is that the RxDart already changed their code and I don't have enough reputation to comment on that question.

Can someone please help?

And is there any other way to contact people in stackoverflow?

Comment: My answer (the non-accepted one) isn't working?

Comment: Hi @RémiRousselet, thanks for the reply. I tried that but I was a bit lost about how I should put the FirebaseUser.uid into the UserModel in that code. And what for is the child: child? How do I call it later in another widget, is it same using Provider.of<UserModel>(context); ?